# Penetration Testing & TCP/IP Interview Question

Tags: penetration-test, ip, protocols, tcp

I recently read that as a penetration tester you should be able to explain the TCP/IP protocol in depth, however these writers never say how in depth is good? Rewriting the protocols by hand type of deep? Just being able to explain the model seems a little to skippy. Where is enough knowledge enough? Explaining what is happening in Wireshark? I ask because I know some crazy good penetration testers that never think about the TCP/IP model when working or even consider it so why it is so important in the interview?

Comment: That depends on what kind of pentesting you are doing. There simply is no one true answer to this question.

Comment: Companies and interviewers will vary on their questions so some might ask and others no. So there is no definite answer but I can give you example. My first junior pentest position I interviewed for they asked me to explain TCP handshake, Syn, Syn Ack, Ack. And tear down , Fin, fin ack, ack. Just naming those and that was as far as they went with that. In my experience during general network pentests, you should know it good enough where you can troubleshoot problems when working with different tools or creating tools and see why something isn't working over the network.

Comment: I consider this question off-topic. It is not a problem of information security itself on how much knowledge you have in a specific area to get some unspecific job. But, if the job would involve penetration testing at the network level (which is not known from your question) it would help a lot if you have a deeper understanding of network protocols like TCP/IP and thus might be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends heavily on the firm and the role. Penetration testing is a varied field where expected knowledge ranges from running off the shelf tools and explaining the output through to manually crafting packets at the wire level. You also get firms that specialize in testing certain products and environments.

There are some jobs where you would be expected to know everything in exact detail. From the packet structure, field locations, congestion control mechanisms and possibly even implementation details from common implementations.

There are others where simply being able to state HTTP is over TCP/IP would be plenty. Someone specializing in in human factors may even only have basic user level computing skills. You might also just be one part of a team. Your skills might be in python frameworks and somebody else works on the lower levels.

I would suggest for any interview this knowledge can't hurt. Even if you specialize in something like content based browser exploitation it can still come in useful. But depending on the actual role it might not be required.

Comment: Good point - when hiring, I hire for the role I look to have filled.  What will this person do?  What do I expect them to grow into?  What skills gap does the team have now?  An even more important skill, to me, is intellectual curiosity.  I can give you experience but I can't give you the desire to learn more or the ability to say, "what happens if..."  and that spirit to try it in a way that doesn't cause damage.

Comment: Thanks all. One thing I can't stand is asking a general question like this so I appreciate the efforts to answer the vague territory it covers. Also @baldPrussian if only all hiring came at the interview the same way you do we probably wouldn't have this so called shortage of talent.

Comment: @Robert: Thanks!  Obviously for senior positions I need to be more focused on skills since I look for them to train the junior staff, but I still look for those soft skills and demonstration to engage in self-guided learning.